# Error "Failed to load data bag item" in Vagrant and Chef Solo

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo, vagrantfile

I am trying to setup a `Vagrant` box with `Chef Solo`. But I am getting the error described below when I try to use the `lxmx_oh_my_zsh::data_bag` recipe.

Here is my `Vargantfile`

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  # Use Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr 64-bit as our operating system
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  # Configurate the virtual machine to use 2GB of RAM
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
  end

  # Forward the Rails server default port to the host
  # config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000

  config.librarian_chef.cheffile_dir = "olympus-kitchen"

  # Use Chef Solo to provision our virtual machine
  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = ["olympus-kitchen/cookbooks", "olympus-kitchen/site-cookbooks"]

    chef.add_recipe "chef-solo-search"
    chef.add_recipe "apt"
    chef.add_recipe "hostname"
    chef.add_recipe "lxmx_oh_my_zsh::data_bag"

    chef.json = {
      set_fqdn: 'Olympus',
      users: ['vagrant']
    }
  end
end
```

Here is my `Cheffile`

```
site "http://community.opscode.com/api/v1"

cookbook 'chef-solo-search'
cookbook 'apt'
cookbook 'build-essential'
cookbook 'hostname'
cookbook 'lxmx_oh_my_zsh'
```

The error I get when I `vagrant provision`

```
==> default: Installing Chef cookbooks with Librarian-Chef...
==> default: Running provisioner: chef_solo...
Generating chef JSON and uploading...
==> default: Running chef-solo...
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: [2014-08-09T15:04:32+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
==> default: [2014-08-09T15:04:32+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 11.8.2 ***
==> default: [2014-08-09T15:04:32+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 10999
==> default: [2014-08-09T15:04:33+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[chef-solo-search]", "recipe[apt]", "recipe[hostname]", "recipe[lxmx_oh_my_zsh::data_bag]"] from JSON
==> default: [2014-08-09T15:04:33+00:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[chef-solo-search], recipe[apt], recipe[hostname], recipe[lxmx_oh_my_zsh::data_bag]]
==> default: [2014-08-09T15:04:33+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [chef-solo-search, apt, hostname, lxmx_oh_my_zsh::data_bag]
==> default: [2014-08-09T15:04:33+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for Olympus
==> default: [2014-08-09T15:04:33+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
==> default: [2014-08-09T15:04:33+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
==> default: [2014-08-09T15:04:33+00:00] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for execute[apt-get-update] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)
==> default: [2014-08-09T15:04:33+00:00] WARN: Previous execute[apt-get-update]: /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/apt/recipes/default.rb:29:in `from_file'
==> default: [2014-08-09T15:04:33+00:00] WARN: Current  execute[apt-get-update]: /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/apt/recipes/default.rb:38:in `from_file'
==> default: [2014-08-09T15:04:33+00:00] ERROR: Failed to load data bag item: "users" "vagrant"
==> default: [2014-08-09T15:04:34+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
==> default: [2014-08-09T15:04:34+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
==> default: [2014-08-09T15:04:34+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
==> default: [2014-08-09T15:04:34+00:00] ERROR: can't convert Array into String
==> default: 
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default: Recipe Compile Error in /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/lxmx_oh_my_zsh/recipes/data_bag.rb
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: TypeError
==> default: ---------
==> default: can't convert Array into String
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: Cookbook Trace:
==> default: ---------------
==> default:   /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/lxmx_oh_my_zsh/recipes/data_bag.rb:4:in `block in from_file'
==> default:   /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/lxmx_oh_my_zsh/recipes/data_bag.rb:3:in `each'
==> default:   /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/lxmx_oh_my_zsh/recipes/data_bag.rb:3:in `from_file'
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: Relevant File Content:
==> default: ----------------------
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/lxmx_oh_my_zsh/recipes/data_bag.rb:
==> default: 
==> default:   1:  include_recipe 'lxmx_oh_my_zsh'
==> default:   2:  
==> default:   3:  node['users'].each do |name|
==> default:   4>>   user = data_bag_item('users', name)
==> default:   5:  
==> default:   6:    if user['oh-my-zsh'] && user['oh-my-zsh']['enabled']
==> default:   7:  
==> default:   8:      if res_action = user['oh-my-zsh']['action']
==> default:   9:        res_action  = res.action.to_sym
==> default:  10:      end
==> default:  11:  
==> default:  12:      lxmx_oh_my_zsh_user user['id'] do
==> default:  13:        home           user['home']
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: [2014-08-09T15:04:32+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
==> default: [2014-08-09T15:04:34+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `chef.data_bags_path` to point to your data bag directory. It defaults to empty. See [the docs](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/chef_solo.html) for reference.